"Expecting member declaration"
I'm having trouble with these lines of code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    var item = "None"
    var price: Double = 16.99
    var Quantity: Int = 2
    println(Calculate(price, item, Quantity)) 
}
fun Calculate(price: Double, item: String, Quantity: Int): Double {
    return(Quantity*price)
}


And at what point exactly are you expecting that println to be executed?

You can't have statements directly under a class, they should be inside a constructor or a method. E.g.:
class MainActivity  {
    var item = "None"
    var price: Double = 16.99
    var Quantity: Int = 2
    fun someFunc() {
        println(Calculate(price, item, Quantity)) 
    }
}


Thanks for the help! If I do that inside the class, where do I write what the method is supposed to do?

@fahim sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Looking at your code I realized that I didn't have a main method and I realized the difference between a class and a method. Thanks for the help your code worked!
